# Is there a term for a boolean expression that only consists of atoms, negations of atoms, and a single unique logical operator?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

For example:

$a \vee b \vee c \vee \neg d$

$a \land \neg b \land \neg c \land d$

these could be described using the term I'm looking for. The following, however, could not be:

$(a \vee b) \land (c \vee \neg d)$

$a \vee (\neg b \land \neg c) \vee d$

as each contains two distinct operators (other than negation)

Comment: Your third and fourth are ambiguous anyways.  $(a\vee b)\wedge c\neq a\vee(b\wedge c)$.

Comment: @JMoravitz I'll edit in parentheses, but that's largely extraneous to the point at hand.

Comment: [Clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA If you write that as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In logic, a [clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)) is an expression formed from a finite collection of [literals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(mathematical_logic)) (atoms or their negations) that is true either whenever at least one of the literals that form it is true (a *disjunctive* clause), or when all of the literals that form it are true (a *conjunctive clause*).